# Substitution using groups from regex works only on one group out of three

Tags: regular-expression, substitute

I want to replace `if (condition) //comment \n\s*{` (\n - newline, \s* 0 or more whitespaces), or rather restructure it, so brace is on same line as if and comment is moved to next one and is indented by one tab more.

It's a Vim practice task, so please don't give me whole solution, instead help me understand what I'm missing.

My regex works and catches what I want (starting with comment on purpose):

`:%s#\(//\)\(.\)*\n\(\s\)*{#{\r\t\3\1 \2#g`

**My replace pattern however doesn't catch groups**, using `\1 \2 \3` doesn't work. To be more precise, only `\1` works.

I get a brace, a new line, one more indent as wanted, then groups (except for `\1` (meaning `//`) are NOT there:

```
if (condition) {
    //
```

No comment text, no tabs/whitespaces aside from one I specifically put there. What am I missing?

Comment: What does that `\n` and `\s` mean? Are they literal characters or used as their original meaning?

Comment: I think `\n` and `\s` are newlines and space characters, as his given regex won't match otherwise.. from what I could make out, `(.\)*\n` should be `(.*\)\n`

Comment: @spasic please post this as an answer so I can accept, as this is precisely what I was missing, my thanks. Groups were captured as they were stated, duh!

Comment: Another note: it's not really worth putting constant text like "`//`" into a group, because you could just put `//` on the other side, rather than `\1`

Comment: @DJMcMayhem definitely. It's just that I was trying to see if there's a problem with groups or what I put in them, thus // was used as test input. Thank you though!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given this text

```
if (condition) //comment
    {
```

the following substitute

```
:%s#\(//\)\(.\)*\n\(\s\)*{#{\r\t\3\1 \2#g
```

gives:

```
if (condition) {
     // t
```

I don't fully understand, but `\(.\)*` would repeat the atom of capturing any single character zero or more times, resulting in capturing the last character of first line `t`

As the intention was to capture all the text following `//`, `*` should have been inside the capturing group. Same goes for `\(\s\)*`. The `g` flag is not needed as well

```
:%s#\(//\)\(.*\)\n\(\s*\){#{\r\t\3\1 \2#
```

which gives

```
if (condition) {
        // comment
```

Using the very magic modifier, the regex would be (see `:h \v` for help)

```
:%s#\v(//)(.*)\n(\s*)\{#{\r\t\3\1 \2#
```

Comment: Thank you. Very magic comes next, it's just that when debugging I went back to escaping manually as I knew it more. Good thing about /g, I used it so often lately that I started appending it by habit...